# Multiply probability distributions in R

Tags: r, probability-density

I'm trying to multiply some probability functions as to update the probability given certain factors. I've tried several things using the `pdqr` and `bayesmeta` packages, but they all work out not the way I intend, what am I missing?

A reproducible example showing two different distributions, a and b, which I want to multiply. That is because, as you notice, b doesn't have measurements in the low values, so a probability of 0. This should be reflected in the updated distribution.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pdqr)
library(bayesmeta)

#measurements
a <- c(1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 2, 6, 9, 10)
b <- c(5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7)

#create probability distribution functions
distr_a <- new_d(a, type = "continuous")
distr_b <- new_d(b, type = "continuous")

#try to combine distributions
summarized <- distr_a + distr_b
multiplied <- distr_a * distr_b
mixture <- form_mix(list(distr_a, distr_b))
convolution <- convolve(distr_a, distr_b)
```

The resulting PDF's are plotted like this:

[image]

The `bayesmeta::convolve()` does the same as summarizing two `pdqr` PDF's and seem to oddly shift the distributions to the right and make them not as high as supposed to be.
Ordinarily multiplying the `pdqr` PDF's leaves a very low probablity overall.
Using the `pdqr::form_mix()` seems to even the PDF's out in between, but leaving probabilies above 0 for the lower x-values.

So, I tried to gain some insight in what I wanted to do, by using the PDF's for a and b to generate probabilities for each x value and multiply that:

```
#multiply distributions manually
x <- c(1:10)
manual <- data.frame(x) %>%
  mutate(a = distr_a(x),
         b = distr_b(x),
         multiplied = a*b)
```

This indeed gives a resulting shape I am after, it however (logically) has too low probabilities:
[image]

I would like to multiply (multiple) PDF's. What am I doing wrong? Are my statistics wrong, or am I missing a usefull function?

UPDATE:
It seems I am a stats noob on this subject, but I would like to achieve something like the below distribution. Given that both situation a and b are true, I would expect the distribution te be something like the dotted line. Is that possible?
[image]

Comment: You are misunderstanding the meaning of the operations in `pdqr`.  `distr_a * distr_b` is not the product of the densities, it is the density of the product of independent realizations of the random variables.  Similarly, `distr_a + distr_b` and `convolve` give the density of the sum of independent realizations, not the sum of the densities.

Comment: @user2554330, thanks for the feedback, in your opinion: what would be a suitable `pdqr` approach?

Comment: I don't know what would be suitable, because you haven't really stated what you are doing this for.  But if you want the product of two densities, just do it as `prod <- function(x) distr_a(x) * distr_b(x)`.  What you get is not a density function, but it is a function that is the product of two densities.

Answer (score 1):

`multiplied` is the correct one. One can check with log-normal distributions. The sum of two independant log-normal random variables is log-normal with **µ = µ_a + µ_b** and **sigma² = sigma²_a + sigma²_b**.

```r
a <- rlnorm(25000, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
b <- rlnorm(25000, meanlog = 1, sdlog = 1)

distr_a <- new_d(a, type = "continuous")
distr_b <- new_d(b, type = "continuous")

distr_ab <- form_trans(
    list(distr_a, distr_b), trans = function(x, y) x*y
)
# or: distr_ab <- distr_a * distr_b

plot(distr_ab, xlim = c(0, 40))
curve(dlnorm(x, meanlog = 1, sdlog = sqrt(2)), add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: `distr_ab <- distr_a * distr_b` is my `multiplied` which has a too low PDF

Comment: But it's correct :-)

Comment: Could you then please explain to me, why it shows probabilities for x-values higher than 10 in my example?

Comment: You have some values a=10 and b=7, and 10*7=? So why would you not have values higher than 10? You seem to be totally confused.

Comment: Ah I read a comment above You don't understand that the density of a product is not the product of the densities...

Comment: it indeed seems like I am misunderstanding some of the key underlying aspects of the updating of PDF's, I've added an intended PDF in the original question. Perhaps I am asking the wrong question at all...

Comment: @JohanVos The random variable **a** has a density **p_a**, the random variable **b** has a density **p_b**. Then (assuming independence), the random variable **ab** has a density, but this density is not the product of **p_a** with  **p_b**. This product is even not a density, it has no mathematical interpretation. If you want the density of **ab**, then I showed you the way.

Answer (score -1):

As demonstrated here:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/05/bayesian-models-in-r-2/

```r
# Example distributions
probs <- seq(0,1,length.out= 100)
prior  <- dbinom(x = 8, prob = probs, size = 10)
lik <- dnorm(x = probs, mean = .5, sd = .1)

# Multiply distributions
unstdPost <- lik * prior

# If you wanted to get an actual posterior, it must be a probability 
# distribution (integrate to 1), so we can divide by the sum:
stdPost <- unstdPost / sum(unstdPost)

# Plot
plot(probs,  prior, col = "black", # rescaled
     type = "l", xlab = "P(Black)", ylab = "Density")
lines(probs, lik / 15, col = "red")
lines(probs, unstdPost, col = "green")
lines(probs, stdPost, col = "blue")
legend("topleft", legend = c("Lik", "Prior", "Unstd Post", "Post"),
       text.col = 1:4, bty = "n")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Your standardization is wrong.  The sum of density values is different from the integral.  You need to multiply `sum(unstdPost)` by the difference in the x values, i.e. 0.01 in your example, which will make the posterior density 100 times higher.

Comment: The marginal likelihood takes the sum for discrete random variables. Values are drawn from a continuous distribution but could still be drawn from a discrete distribution if we were given them without knowledge of the underlying distribution (as in the OP's case). More useful model would presumably be continuous though.

Comment: In my example using `distr_a * distr_b`  doesn't work out the way in your example. Could you use my distributions in your example?

Comment: @socialscientist:  The random variable in your posterior is `probs` not `x`, and it is continuous on the [0,1] interval.

Comment: Just noticed:  you appear to have prior and likelihood reversed.  `dbinom(8, prob = probs, size = 10)` makes sense as a likelihood, but you have named it `prior`; `dnorm(x = probs, mean = .5, sd = .1)` makes sense as an approximation to a prior, but you have named it `lik`.  This doesn't matter for the posterior calculation since you just multiply them and normalize, but it will confuse people.